# Cycle logic fail / JAVA

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to scan from keyboard an int and print the fibonacci numbers smaller than the inserted.
Now it prints all the smallers and one bigger.
Need to change the while.

```
public class tp2 {

 public static int Fibo(int pos){
      int retornado=0;
      if(pos==0 || pos==1){
       retornado=pos;
      }else{
       retornado=Fibo(pos-2)+Fibo(pos-1);
      }
      return retornado;
     }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tope,i, numero;
    numero=0;
    i=0;
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese un entero tope :");
    tope = stdin.nextInt();
    while (numero<tope){
        numero=Fibo(i);
        System.out.println(numero);
        i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: done
`
  while (Fibo(i)<tope){
   System.out.println(Fibo(i));
   i++;
  }`

Comment: That's a bad way of doing that. It calls `Fibo(i)` twice..

Comment: Its calling fibo twice in order to get fibonacci by recursiveness
And then calls fibo to decide whether to print it, and then to print it.

Comment: It's working fine but you call same function 2 times in same block when you could instead assign this to variable. In this case this won't have huge impact but in future if You expect same results like here better assign result to variable so you won't face performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the prettiest solution but changing the your current while to :

```
while ((numero=Fibo(i))<tope){
    System.out.println(numero);
    i++;
}
```

does the trick

Comment: Thanks! Got to this directly.
`  while (Fibo(i)<tope){
   System.out.println(Fibo(i));
   i++;
  }
`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
numero=Fibo(i);
while (numero<tope){
    System.out.println(numero);
    i++;
    numero=Fibo(i);
}
```